# Direct transfer of big files between two computers online without using a server

Tags: windows, gratis

What permanent (not trial) free of charge software can I get to directly transfer big files to another computer over the internet (to and from someone far from me).

Both computers use Windows so being cross-plataform isn't important.

It should be able to transfer files of at least 50 GBs but preferably allow up to around 200 GBs (per file without splitting). In other words, with a max size of at least in the dozens of GBs, if not hundreds.

Use direct transfer between the two computers (without uploading the file to a server and then downloading it from the receiving computer).

Being a lightweight and easy to use program is preferable.

I have seen some related questions so let me know in the comments if you believe it's duplicated so I can reply if I agree, or if not, explain why I think my question is different.

Comment: You could set up a web or ftp server (e.g., apache or IIS) on one of the workstations, then download the file via http/ftp from the other...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Not the first time I hear of ftp but I have no idea how that works, if it's free, and if I need to use a server (upload and then download instead of directly transfer).

Comment: In either case (ftp or web), one of the two computers _is_ the "server" and you use the other computer to download from the first.

Comment: Depending on which version of Windows you're using (home/pro/enterprise), I believe there's support built in (but not by default turned on).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'm still hoping to see if there is a better alternative (easy to use, fast, no small size restrictions, etc).

Comment: Set up one of the PCs as a server and FTP the file?

Comment: @Mawg - That's exactly what I proposed in my Answer below.

Comment: I will give it a try but I'm not very positive that I will get it working.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin and I did upvote you :-) But, if the OP doesn't have Windows Professional, there are other ways. Btw, I buy my Windows & Office licenses (MSVC architect too) ***legally*** from eBay for under $10. Many people don't know that license resale is legal and so don't look there.

Comment: @Mawg I did got mine that way. I'm trying out on the work computers right now but I will try when I get home too.

Comment: The work computer also already has WinSCP setup which is used for something like that but it wasn't me who set it up.

Comment: @Mawg - I've updated my Answer to note that it's actually supported in Home as well.

Answer (score 2):

Peer to Peer Transfer would help you.

Torrent - Create a torrent and Share the Link with the Other PC.

Happy File Sharing.

Cheers!!

Comment: Welcome aboard! A good answer, although a little more explanation would be nice. Since we are all about recommending an app, can you recommend some software? Perhaps an app to create the torrent?

Answer (score 1):

Windows, at least at the Professional level or above, comes with support for setting up either a web server or an ftp server, and also comes with clients for both. There are [instructions for setting up an ftp server on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-ftp-server-windows-10); once the server is set up, you can [access it from the other computer using either File Explorer or the command-line ftp client program](https://www.howtogeek.com/272176/how-to-connect-to-ftp-servers-in-windows-without-extra-software/).

The speed of your file transfer is limited only by your connection bandwidth; there is some overhead, but not really a lot; while setup isn't trivial, it's not overly complex, and it'll handle files as large as you need, depending on the quality of your connection.

Total add-on cost: zero!

*N.B. According to [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1245472/does-windows-10-home-edition-have-iis), Windows 10 Home Edition also has IIS, so you should be able to do this with Home as well - I wasn’t sure if it was possible with Home as I’ve never used anything less than Pro.*

Answer (score 0):

If you secure both ends against hackers with firewalls and credentialed logins you could just use "Windows file and printer sharing".

This assumes your ISP doesn't block the ports on either end.

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/schollz/croc for this

It works crossplatform and needs no setup. Just running croc on both pcs (download and double click)